# How can I prevent Navigator push from refreshing the screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am writing a flutter program where the user should select a value from a DropdownButtonFormField. once the selection is made, the choice should be displayed on the dropdown. I use a push route to get the data from a second screen in which the choice is utilized. My problem is after selecting the option, the page refreshes and therefore doesnt show the selected value on the dropdown.

Below is my code:

I create the Dropdownbuttonformfield in a file called shared.dart so I can call it in multiple files:

```
  class UserDropdownList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserDropdownListState createState() => _UserDropdownListState();
   }
  class _UserDropdownListState extends State<UserDropdownList> {

  String currentUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<List<User>>(context) ?? [];


    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      isExpanded: true,
      decoration: textInputDecoration,
      value: currentUser,

      hint: Text(
        'Incoming Officer',
      ),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() => currentUser = val);
        var route = MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          FinalForm(chosenUser: currentUser,)
          );
          Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      },
      // onChanged: (val) => setState(() => currentUser = val),
      items: user.map((user){
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: user.userId,
          child: Text(user.name)
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
      }
    }
```

I then call the Custom button in my main page like so

```
class FinalForm extends StatefulWidget {

//code for importing selected user
  final String chosenUser;
  FinalForm({Key key, this.chosenUser}) : super (key: key);

  @override
  _FinalForm createState() => _FinalFormState();
}

class _FinalFormState extends State<FinalForm> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Final Form')
      ),
      body: Form( 
        child: Center(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
            children: <Widget>[

            SizedBox(height: 20.0),

            Align(
              child: Text( 
                'Select Incoming Officer',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              )
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),

            StreamProvider<List<User>>.value(
              value: DatabaseService().users,
              child: UserDropdownList(),

            ),



            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text("${widget.chosenUser}"),

          ],),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to keep the selected value on the dropdown or prevent the screen from reloading?

Comment: If you are navigating away from the current page, what does it matter if the page rebuilds? For that matter, is there even any reason to be calling `setState` here?

Comment: The dropdown is a  custom widget that I have created myself. I call it on a screen in a different stateful widget where the data is consumed. I want it to only push the data to the second screen but not rebuild the entire thing

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be navigating to begin with. You can't navigate without rebuilding (since that would defeat the purpose of navigating).

Comment: no, you cannot prevent it from rebuilding - you have to be prepared for `build` method to be called at any time

Comment: what would be the best way to push the data without rebuilding?

Comment: if you are using `Navigator.pop` from the child `Widget` the parent `Widget` will always be rebuilt - you just cannot prevent it

Comment: your `currentUser` is not set either when declared in `String currentUser;` or inside `initState` method

Comment: Even if I set it to null, my main challenge is accessing it in FinalForm

Comment: simply set it to some `user.userId`

Answer (score 0):

If you are navigating away from the current page / view, it would make sense for the current dropdown selection to be lost. You can pass the current selection as an argument to the push function to redisplay on the new page. Hth

Comment: the issue is that I am not navigating from the current page. i just use the navigator to push the selected data to the stateful widget in which I call the custom Dropdownformfield. So ultimately, I still want to display the Dropdown, just now, I need it with the data

Comment: @David You _are_ navigating. That's what `Navigator.push` does - navigates. Don't use it if all you are trying to do is move data around.

Comment: I was using that as a last option, what would be the best option to push the data without navigating?

Comment: @David "if you are using Navigator.pop from the child Widget the parent Widget will always be rebuilt - you just cannot prevent it "

Comment: @pskink That's what I have realized, so I am stuck on how to move a String value from the Drop-down that I have created in one Stateful widget and use it in another Stateful widget